# Finding mean, variance, and distribution of $Y=X_1+X_2+X_3+\cdots+X_n$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{n}$ be random random variables.  So say we have the following multivariate pdf:

$f(x_{1}, x_{2},..., x_{n})= e^{-x_{1}-x_{2}- \cdots-x_{n}}$ from $0\lt x_{i}\lt\infty$, where $i=1,..., n$ and its $0$ elsewhere.  How would you find the distribution of $Y$ and the mean and variance of $Y$?

I mean I know the formulas of the mean and variance but I'm not so sure by what distribution is looking for. Please help.

Comment: The expected value of the sum is the sum of the expected values.  The variance of the sum is $$\sum_i \sum_j \text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$$For the separable pdf, calculating these covariance terms is trivial.  The off-diagonal terms are zero and the variance terms are $1$.  Therefore, the variance of the sum is simply $n$.

Comment: Do you know about moment generating functions? This would be the easiest way to approach the distribution of the sum.

Comment: The sum of iid exponential random variables has an Erlang or Gamma distribution.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$f(x_{1}, x_{2},...x_{n})= e^{-x_{1}-x_{2}- \cdots-x_{n}}=\Pi_{j=1}^ne^{-x_j}$$

therefore $x_j$'s are independent each with pdf $e^{-x}$ on $0<x<\infty$. $$EX=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=1$$ $$EX^2=\int_0^{\infty}x^2e^{-x}dx=2$$ hence $EX_j=1$ and $var(X_j)=1$. Therefore $$EY=\sum EX_j =n$$ and $$var Y= \sum var(X_j) =n$$